# How to Add page number dynamically to footer in word file that create using C# StringBuilder - HTML

Tags: c#, html, stringbuilder

I created a word file using HTML - `StringBuilder`.Now I want to add page numbers dynamically to the footer. I tried it using `counter-increment`. But it is not working.If i hardcode a number inside the `<div style='mso-element:footer' id=f1>` tag it is working.but i want to do it dynamically.
Please help me to do that.

```
            StringBuilder wordfile = new StringBuilder();

            wordfile.Append("<html>");
            wordfile.Append("<head>");
            wordfile.Append("<style type='text/css'>");
            wordfile.Append("@page Section1 {");
            wordfile.Append(appSettingCache.GetValue("ExportPageMargin"));
            wordfile.Append("size:8.5in 11.0in;");
            wordfile.Append("mso-page-orientation:landscape;");
            wordfile.Append("mso-header-margin:0.5in;");
            wordfile.Append("mso-header: h1;");
            wordfile.Append("mso-footer-margin:0.5in;");
            wordfile.Append("mso-footer: f1;");
            wordfile.Append("}");

            wordfile.Append("div.Section1 {page:Section1;}");

            wordfile.Append("p.headerFooter { margin:0in; text-align: center; }");
            wordfile.Append(".abc:before{ counter-increment: page; content: counter(page);}");  //define counter-increment
            wordfile.Append("</style>");
            wordfile.Append("</head>");
            wordfile.Append("<body><div class=Section1>");



            wordfile.Append("<table style='margin-left:50in;'><tr style='height:1pt;mso-height-rule:exactly'>");
            wordfile.Append("<td>");
            wordfile.Append("<div style='mso-element:header' id=h1>");
            wordfile.Append("<p class=headerFooter>");

            //Header content
            wordfile.Append(headerImagePath);

            wordfile.Append("</p>");
            wordfile.Append("</div>");
            wordfile.Append("&nbsp;");
            wordfile.Append("</td>");

            wordfile.Append("<td>");
            wordfile.Append("<div style='mso-element:footer' id=f1>");
            wordfile.Append("<p class=headerFooter>");

            wordfile.Append("<div class=abc>");  //the place i tried counter-increment
            wordfile.Append("</div>");

            wordfile.Append("</p>");
           
            wordfile.Append("</div>");
            wordfile.Append("&nbsp;");
            wordfile.Append("</td></tr></table>");
            wordfile.Append("</div></body>");
            wordfile.Append("</html>");
```

Comment: An HTML file is not a Word document. To create a Word document see [here](https://github.com/dotnet/Open-XML-SDK).

Comment: after creating this HTML I convert it to word separately

Comment: It's not clear why you would create an HTML file and then attempt to convert it to a Word document. Please explain in more detail what you are trying to accomplish. This approach seems misguided and perhaps even incorrect.

Comment: Dynamically how? When you call the method? When you print the page?